# Cucumber::Core::Gherkin::ParseError: how to solve it?

Tags: ruby, parsing, cucumber, capybara

I am a newbie in ruby and want to build an autotesting system for a webapplication. I started to study the bunch od capybara + cucumber on ruby.

I found an example and tried to reproduce it. There is the project sturcture:

```
devTests
     features
      step_definitions
        test_steps.rb
      support
        env.rb
      tests
        test_send_mail.feature
     Gemfile
     Gemfile.lock
```

Feature file has the text:

```
Feature: Log in to site
  Scenario: Log in to site on English
    Given Go to page "http://localhost:3000/login"
    And Select text "English" in dropdownlist id "lang"
    And Wait 5 second
    And Input text "admin" in field with id "session_email"
    And Input text "123" in field with id "session_password"
    And Press button with text "Log in"
    And Wait 5 second
```

and step_definitions

```
Given(/^Go to page "(.*?)"$/) do |page|
  visit page
end

Given(/^Select text "(.*?)" in dropdownlist id "(.*?)"$/) do |text, select_id|
  find("//select[@id='#{select_id}']/option[text()='#{text}']").click
end

Given(/^Wait (\d+) second(?:|s)$/) do |sec|
  sleep sec.to_i
end 

Given(/^Input text "(.*?)" in field with id "(.*?)"$/) do |text, field_id|
  find("//input[@id='#{field_id}']").set(text)
end

Given(/^Input text "(.*?)" in field with id "(.*?)"$/) do |text, field_id|
  find("//input[@id='#{field_id}']").set(text)
end

Given(/^Press button with text "(.*?)"$/) do |text|
  find("//input[@value='#{text}']").click
end

Given(/^Wait (\d+) second(?:|s)$/) do |sec|
  sleep sec.to_i
end
```

When I run the test, then I got parser errors

```
PS D:\07 TestConwize\devTests> cucumber
*** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/) to get coloured output on Windows
features/tests/test_send_mail.feature: Parser errors:
(1:1): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'Feature: Log in to site'
(2:3): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'Scenario: Log in to site on English'    
(3:5): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'Given Go to page "http://localhost:3000/login"'
(4:5): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'And Select text "English" in dropdownlist id "lang"'
(5:5): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'And Wait 5 second'
(6:5): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'And Input text "admin" in field with id 
"session_email"'
(7:5): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'And Input text "123" in field with id "session_password"'
(8:5): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'And Press button with text "Log in"'    
(9:5): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'And Wait 5 second' (Cucumber::Core::Gherkin::ParseError)
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:34:in `rescue in document'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:28:in `document'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core.rb:30:in `block in parse'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core.rb:29:in `each'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core.rb:29:in `parse'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core.rb:21:in `compile'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:75:in `run!'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:34:in `execute!'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
```

I’ve been fighting all day, but I can’t understand what the problem is. 
Could you help me?

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext. [Images of plaintext are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). You have access to the plaintext; please copy and paste it into your question.

Comment: Can you check for any invisible characters in your file? Think Byte Order Marker,  ect.

Comment: anothermh, sorry for my mistake but is inot plain text it is file structure. I try to correct my post.

Comment: mpkorstanje, you guessed! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to add some tags?

Feature: Log in to site
@Example
Scenario: Log in to site on English
Given Go to page "http://localhost:3000/login"
And Select text "English" in dropdownlist id "lang"
And Wait 5 second